# MySQL Replication Error on AWS RDS: Access Denied for SUPER or REPLICATION_SLAVE_ADMIN Privileges

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

I am logged in to AWS RDS database using MySQL Workbench.

MySQL version: 8.0.35
Logged in using master user: admin@'%'

We do a replication from Master to Slave between a Windows Server and another Windows Server:

```
Windows Server (MySQL - Master) --> Windows Server (MySQL - Slave)
```

As we've changed to AWS, now we need to do the same replication but from RDS to a Windows server:

```
AWS RDS (MySQL - Master) --> Windows Server (MySQL - Slave)
```

To do the replication we run the following command:

```
CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='123.123.12.12',
MASTER_USER='user',
MASTER_PORT=3306,
MASTER_PASSWORD='123456',
MASTER_LOG_FILE='binlog.000004',
MASTER_LOG_POS=7947 FOR CHANNEL '123.123.12.12';

START SLAVE FOR CHANNEL '123.123.12.12';

Error: Error Code: 1227. Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER or REPLICATION_SLAVE_ADMIN privilege(s) for this operation
```

RDS user is master user (admin), there is another user rdsadmin, but is private to localhost. RDS does not give SUPER privilegies to admin user.

1 - Is there a way to give SUPER/REPLICATION_SLAVE_ADMIN privilegies to admin user, or through parameter group?

2 - If not, isn't it possible to do Master/Slave replication on RDS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RDS doesn't grant users the SUPER privilege, even to the root user.

Instead, AWS RDS implements a set of stored procedures to control replication. You can call the procedures, and the procedures manage replication in the manner prescribed by AWS.

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/mysql-stored-proc-replicating.html for documentation on these procedures.

Comment: `mysql.rds_set_external_master` works only for one channel, it means I can't do something like `CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='123.123.12.12, ... FOR CHANNEL '123.123.12.12'`, our company structure was a main Windows Server replicating to multiple others Windows Server. Is there a way for me to keep using this approach in RDS? Or I will need to change our company strategy?

Comment: Right, RDS doesn't solve all needs. You can contact your account rep at AWS and request this feature, but be prepared that they might not implement it for months or years. In the meantime, if RDS doesn't have the features you need, you may need to operate MySQL Server manually on an EC2 instance.